# render/draw or input first?

Tags: lwjgl, game-loop, pygame

When creating the main game loop, what order should things generally happen? That is, should I be getting input, doing logic and then rendering, or something else? does this even matter? when I was coding with Python and Pygame the tutorial I was using pointed me towards the aforementioned method. however, [this tutorial for LWJGL2](http://thecodinguniverse.com/lwjgl-window/) does it like this:

```
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
// While no attempt to close the display is made..
// Put render code here.
// Put input handling code here.
Display.update();
// Refresh the display and poll input.
Display.sync(60);
// Wait until 16.67 milliseconds have passed. (Maintain 60 frames-per-second)
```

and (so far) doesn't seem to have hinted at logic (though I assume it will later on, and looks like it might put it last).

So which should I be using? Does it matter at all?
I'm using LWJGL2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing your main loop and updating logic, you've got two basic strategies, which you're probably aware of: fixed time steps and dynamic time steps. Either way your updates will happen at some time.

There are basically two ways to write this - both which you identified already:

Version 1:

```
while (running) {
    update();
    draw();
}
```

Version 2:

```
while (running) {
    draw();
    update();
}
```

Note that `update()` can act as a real black box here. It doesn't matter how the updates happen, i.e. whether there's some fixed time step or not.

Now let's unwind 3 iterations of that main loop and you'll get...

Version 1:

```
// iteration 1
update();
draw();
// iteration 2
update();
draw();
// iteration 3
update();
draw();
```

Version 2:

```
// iteration 1
draw();
update();
// iteration 2
draw();
update();
// iteration 3
draw();
update();
```

Skip the comments and you'll notice that both implementations are essentially the same.

However, there are two tiny tidbits to mention:

- When you run the main loop for the **first time**, if there's no `update()` call before the first `draw()`, you might end up with **one drawn frame** you don't want to be there or with some **undefined behavior** (depends on your overall design).
- If you're using **vertical synchronization** (or it's forced), it will typically happen at the end of `draw()`, when the current scene/back buffer is presented. This means that if you're drawing first, your input will always **lag behind by one (display) frame**. Depending on your frame rate this might be very noticeable to the user.

Due to this (and probably due to simple logic, i.e. you have to setup what you want to draw first), I think pretty much any game will usually update first, draw second.

Answer (score 3):

The typical implementation is Update first, then Render. I guess this is because it reduces input latency. In Update-First you see changes on the current frame (U - update, R - render, F - frame, [wait] - wait for V-Sync):

`U1->R1->[wait]->F1 => U2->R2->[wait]->F2`

In Update-Last you see changes on the next frame (F1 is two [wait] later of U1):

`R0->U1->[wait]->F0 => R1->U2->[wait]->F1`

Also update-first gives you a chance to drop render in case it took more time than expected, so you could catch-up. I don't really see any possible benefits in render-first approach.

Answer (score 1):

One call to Render() usually equates to many calls to Update() and Render() is usually called about 60 times per second.

That usually equates to:

```
void Frame(float elapsedTime)
{
    static float accumulatedElapsedTime = 0;
    accumulatedElapsedTime += elapsedTime;
    while (accumulatedElapsedTime >= fixedTimeStep)
    {
        Update(fixedTimeStep);
        accumulatedElapsedTime -= fixedTimeStep;
    }
    Render();
}
```

This also implies a distinct separation between render-code and state-code.

Update() should, ideally, only modify data in buffers. Render() uploads that data (preferably only changed data) and tells the GPU how to use it.

Comment: you are saying they are usually in completely different threads? and where does logic fit in?

Comment: IMO, you have `Update()` and `Render()` flipped around.  You should be updating at a fixed interval, and rendering as fast as possible, with interpolation.  Of course, your update frequency may be higher than your refresh rate, but it should still be fixed.  This makes your integration (such as in physics simulation) much more deterministic.

Comment: You're not presenting the same image over and over again.  In the more prevalent case, where the refresh rate is higher than the update frequency, you are interpolating between the last two "snapshots".  While this adds a worst-case latency of your update interval, it keeps physics deterministic and stable.  This page goes into a lot more detail: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: @Boreal, is it better, now? Can't screw up copy-and-paste...

Comment: Using the name `elapsedTime` confused me, since the value is being decremented. Propably `DeLoreanTime` would suit better :)

Comment: The actual code calls into the StepTimer class (from the DirectXTK). It uses many, better-named variables and accurately handles "left overs".

Comment: One tiny thing: You'll most likely want to limit the number of updates per iteration to get at least one drawn frame out once in a while. Otherwise the program will just hang for quite some time, e.g. after moving the window with the mouse. If your frame rate drops below - no idea, 5 or 10 fps, you shouldn't worry about precise timing/animation anymore.